# RecyclerView card items not centering, when RecyclerView parent is ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of card views which has the flag of the country and name of it. The CardView has a ConstraintLayout as a child for aligning the views inside, and has a LinearLayout as parent.

The RecyclerView in MainActivity has a ConstraintLayout as Parent(which is the parent view by default created by AndroidStudio when doing a new project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- MAIN ACTIVITY XML-->
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:layout_width="@dimen/card_view_item_main_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_item_main_height">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/countryCardImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imagen_pais"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countryCardText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
                />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- ITEMMAIN.XML -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".main.ui.main.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/listMain"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the first layout is meant for your activity, and the second layout is meant for the recycler view item, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your item root view, the `layout_gravity="center"` is not going to work on `LinearLayout` with `layout_width="wrap_content:` on a `RecyclerView`, so you could try changing its width to `match_parent`, and either change the gravity to `android:gravity="center"` or move `android:layout_gravity="center"` to its child view:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width=“match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/card_view_item_main_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_item_main_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Comment: It worked :O, but why do I need to set the root element to match parent and move the gravity to the child element?

Comment: Well firstly, you can't set layout_gravity on root element because the recycler view will provide layout param for each item view, and we can't guarantee that the layout param will support layout_gravity, or even if it does, it will most likely be replaced. So our only option left is to make the root element to have match with the recycler view, and set layout_gravity on the item child, or layout_centerInParent if the root is a relative layout (you'll get the idea!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in layout item, you set the layout_width="wrap_content" in LinearLayout, and in main layout, layout_width in Recyclerview is 0dp (must be match_parent) so it's not center in main layout because the main layout depend on item layout => wrong with this case.
In your layout item, change like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Please add some detail to your answer - how exactly it solves the problem stated in the question?